# Agora React-native voice call implementation

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am trying to implement agora voice-call using functional component in react-native.
iam also used agora-rn-uikit for video calling ,can i use this packege for voice call ui

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [this repo](https://github.com/EkaanshArora/Agora-RN-Audio-Broadcast) for audio broadcast app in react-native.

If you're using the agora-rn-uikit, you'll have to make some changes to the UI layer to adapt the library to an audio only use-case.